# How to align and merge texts into a single cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to do like this

from:

```
| Hello World Hey |
```

to a single cell and row like this:

```
|Hello |
|World |
|Hey   |
```

I have tried:

```
style2.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
cell.setCellStyle(style2);
```

and also:

```
style2.setVerticalAlignment(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
cell.setCellStyle(style2);
```

But nothing work the way I want, can someone help ?

Comment: what are you getting after doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the whole text in single cell, then you need to wrap it as we do in excel. For tahat yoou need to set wrap text as true.

```
 style2.setWrapText(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below approach:

```
CellStyle cellStyle = row.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
    cellStyle.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_LEFT);
    lastCell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Create a new cell style from workbook.

```
CellStyle cellStyle = row.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
```